# In Sprite kit, how to use the microphone of iPhone?

Tags: iphone, swift, sprite-kit, microphone

For example, I want to design a gameplay which need user to blow the microphone and the microphone can identify this behaviour.

And because I'm a newbie in developer, I can only understand swift rather then Object C, a complete code example is the best I think.

I know it's unprofessional to ask a question like this , straightforward and do not make any effort, if make anyone feel like that, I'm apologise first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to detect blow from mic not voice in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286768/how-to-detect-blow-from-mic-not-voice-in-iphone)

Comment: http://www.whatsoniphone.com/blog/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/

Comment: @ZeMoon Hey buddy, I'm sorry but I have to ask this continually because the question you mentioned do not make sense to me.